# Is there some substitute for overloading?

Tags: java

I'm working on this project and I was creating class **ExportToFile**.This class needs to handle export of multiple HashMaps. Each hashmap has object of different class as **value**. Firstly I thought to use overloaded methods to do this. Here's code how I was thinking to do it.

```
public void exportList(HashMap<String, Faculty> facultyList, String nameOfFile) {

    }

    public void exportList(HashMap<String, FieldOfStudy> list, String nameOfFile) {

    }

    public void exportList(HashMap<String, Group> list, String nameOfFile) {

    }

    public void exportList(HashMap<String, Subject> list, String nameOfFile) {

    }

    public void exportList(HashMap<String, Student> list, String nameOfFile) {

    }

    public void exportList(HashMap<String, Teacher> list, String nameOfFile) {

    }

    public void exportList(HashMap<String, Admin> list, String nameOfFile) {

    }
```

Ofcourse after writing that I realized it can't be done like that because the methods have arguments of the same type. One thought came to my mind to try it like this: I thought to have one method with value **Object** and in the body of method I would determine what class does the object belongs to.

```
public void exportList(HashMap<String, Object> facultyList, String nameOfFile) {
        

    }
```

I don't know if it could be done like that and if yes, I don't know how. Any ideas how to solve this problem of mine?

Comment: How about making the method generic? `public <T> void exportList(HashMap<String, T> facultyList, String nameOfFile)`. Of course it depends on how you use the value type. Otherwise I suppose `public void exportList(HashMap<String, ? extends Object> facultyList, String nameOfFile)`

Comment: "I don't know if it could be done like that" Well this depends on what you do inside `exportList`. Can you show what you are going to do with the `HashMap` parameter?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: It's confusing to have a map parameter named `list`. It provides misleading information.

Comment: If all classes share an interface you could use that as value-type.

Comment: If you *really* don't want to just use different method names, you could just check the class of the first map value in order to know what to do.

Comment: @Sweeper I don't have that code written yet, but the method purpose is to export data from HashMap to .csv file.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle How do I check what class is first map value?

Comment: If you are the owner of the value classes like Admin, Group, then you can have a common interface something like `Exportable`, which provides the values of its instance variables as a list or csv string. Then, your exporting function can be very generic enough, that you need to get the values and write to a csv file.

Comment: @marek just take the first that comes : `list.iterator().next()` which should give you an `Entry` with a key and a value then `getClass()` on the value. But for the readability of the project, you should really create different method names. Maybe create 7 method names `exportStudents`, `exportTeachers` etc then create one method `exportList` that checks the type of the first value that comes and redirects to the right method.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Thanks, that sounds good. I'll do it like you said

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle  I tried it like this. The case gives me error.' public void exportList(HashMap<String, Object> list, String nameOfFile) {
        HashMap<String, Subject> subjects = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator it = list.entrySet().iterator();
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        switch(pair.getValue().getClass()) {
            case Faculty:

                break;
        }' Could you help fixing it?

Comment: @marek `case Faculty.class` maybe ? (sorry, I have not coded in Java since 3 years). Could you show the error message ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Yes, that works. `public void exportList(HashMap<String, Object> list, String nameOfFile) {   if (Faculty.class.equals(pair.getValue().getClass())) {
            exportFaculties((HashMap<String, Faculty>)list);
        }}` . Right now the problem is that **exportFaculties** needs HashMap<String, Faculty> as argument. Export list has HashMap<String ,Object>.  I get error that **Object** can't be cast to **Faculty**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make it work with overloading because of type erasure. Also, it would be bad for code readbility.

You can instead create methods with different names for each export :

```java
public void exportFaculty(HashMap<String, Faculty> facultyList, String nameOfFile) {}
public void exportFieldOfStudy(HashMap<String, FieldOfStudy> list, String nameOfFile) {}
public void exportGroup(HashMap<String, Group> list, String nameOfFile) {}
```

But, also because of type erasure, you cannot check the type of the map value. But instead of that, you can still take the first element of the map then dynamically get its class:

```java
Class<?> classOfFirstElt = map.values().iterator().next().getClass();
```

Then, you can use some if/else statements in order to call the right methods (I tried with switch case but it seems that it is not possible)

```java
if(classOfFirstElt.equals(Faculty.class)) {
  exportFaculty((HashMap<String, Faculty>)map, nameOfFile);
} else if (classOfFirstElt.equals(FieldOfStudy.class)) {
  exportFielfOfStudy((HashMap<String, FieldOfStudy>)map, nameOfFile);
} else if(classOfFirstElt.equals(Group.class)) {
  exportGroup((HashMap<String, FieldOfGroup>)map, nameOfFile);
}
```

As a bonus, if you don't want to deal with "unchecked cast" warnings, you can create a helper method for that :

```java
private <T> HashMap<String, T> castMap(HashMap<String, ?> map) {
  return (HashMap<String, T>)map;
}
```

This way, there will be only one warning in this method and the code becomes cleaner :

```java
public void exportList(HashMap<String, ?> map, String nameOfFile) {
  Class<?> classOfFirstElt = map.values().iterator().next().getClass();
  if(classOfFirstElt.equals(Faculty.class)) {
    exportFaculty(castMap(map), nameOfFile);
  } else if (classOfFirstElt.equals(FieldOfStudy.class)) {
    exportFieldOfStudy(castMap(map), nameOfFile);
  } else if(classOfFirstElt.equals(Group.class)) {
    exportGroup(castMap(map), nameOfFile);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps:

```
public <T> void exportList(HashMap<String, T> list, String file) {
    
    // to avoid NullPointer
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        Map.Entry<String, T> pair = (Map.Entry<String, T>) list.entrySet().iterator().next();
        
        if (Faculty.class.equals(pair.getValue().getClass())) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, Faculty> facultyList = (HashMap<String, Faculty>) list;
            exportFaculty(facultyList, file);
        }
        else if (...) {
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

But must say I don't like the `Faculty.class.equals(pair.getValue().getClass())` approach. Should look for something more elegant.

**Edited**

Like this much more:

```
    if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
        
        T t = map.values().iterator().next();
        if (t instanceof Faculty) {
            exportFaculty((HashMap<String, Faculty>) map, file);
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already pointed out, it is not possible to have all the different functions as overloads in one class. What you can do is that you can write an interface and have all the different functions be an implementation of that interface:

```
public interface Exporter<T> {
    void exportList(Map<String, T> facultyList, String nameOfFile);

    Class<T> exportType();
}
```

The method `exportType` is not necessary, but it can help when using the interface. An implementation looks like this:

```
@Component
class FacultyExporter implements Exporter<Faculty> {

    @Override
    public void exportList(Map<String, Faculty> facultyList, String nameOfFile) {
        // implementation for values of type Faculty
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Faculty> exportType() {
        return Faculty.class;
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed I added a `@Component` annotation to the implementation of the `Exporter` interface. You could omit that if you are not using Spring, but if you do use Spring, you can just autowire all your different exporters in the `ExportToFile` class to use them there. Otherwise it would be necessary to populate the `exporters` list in the following class manually.

```
@Component
class ExportToFile {

    @Autowired
    private List<Exporter<?>> exporters;

    public <T> void exportList(Map<String, T> list, String nameOfFile) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            exporters.get(0).exportList(Collections.emptyMap(), nameOfFile);
            return;
        }
        Class<?> type = list.values().iterator().next().getClass();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Optional<Exporter<T>> exporter = exporters
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.exportType().equals(type))
                .findAny()
                .map(e -> (Exporter<T>) e);
        exporter.ifPresentOrElse(
                e -> e.exportList(list, nameOfFile), () -> {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("type not supported");
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Now, this implementation of `exportList` checks for the type of the values in the given map. I assumed here that for an empty list, we could just use an arbitrary exporter, and thus, we are just using the first exporter there is.

If there is at least one an element in the map, we take the class of the first element, look for the right exporter with that type, and apply the exporter to the map.

We could get rid of the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` by defining the type class as an additional parameter of `exportList`, but without that parameter, it is a bit more convenient. And in fact we can be sure that the cast succeeds, because we checked against the `exportType` of the `Exporter`.

In this implementation of `exportList`, I decided to throw an exception if there is no suitable `Exporter`.

If you want to add another supported type, you just write a new `Exporter` implementation, and have to do nothing more.